# Access Array list from one constructor to another constructor android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get an array list from one constructor another. I tried many ways but not successfully. please see my code below. If this is not possible please suggest me any alternative way to achieve this approach. this code is in my adapter

```
ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList = new ArrayList<CuisineCategory>();

ArrayList<CuisineCategory> dataList;

public CuisineAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mydataList = mydataList;

    }

    public CuisineAdapter(Context context, CuisineListToggleListener listToggleListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listToggleListener = listToggleListener;
        this.dataList = new ArrayList<>();

       this.dataList = mydataList;<- this is not working

    }
```

`mydataList` contains the array list and I want to use it in the second constructor

please see my full code of the adapter

```
public class CuisineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CuisineAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList = new ArrayList<>();

    private ArrayList<CuisineCategory> dataList;

    private CuisineListToggleListener listToggleListener;

    public CuisineAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList) {
        this.context = context;
        //this.dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.mydataList = mydataList;

//        for(CuisineCategory dt: mydataList){
//
//            //Log.e("data:", String.valueOf(dt.getTitle()));
//        }
    }

    public CuisineAdapter(Context context, CuisineListToggleListener listToggleListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listToggleListener = listToggleListener;

        this.dataList = new ArrayList<>();

        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Popular"));
        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Main course"));
        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Lunch"));
        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Breakfast"));
        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Dinner"));
        this.dataList.add(new CuisineCategory("Appetizer"));

    }




    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_cuisine_cat, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(dataList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private LinearLayout rootLayout;
        private TextView cuisineCategory;
        private ImageView cuisineItemToggle;
        private RecyclerView cuisineItemList;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cuisineItemList = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cuisineItemList);
            cuisineCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cuisineCategory);
            cuisineItemToggle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cuisineItemToggle);
            rootLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    CuisineCategory category = dataList.get(pos);
                    category.setSelected(!category.isSelected());
                    Collections.swap(dataList, 0, pos);
                    notifyItemMoved(category.isSelected() ? pos : 0, category.isSelected() ? 0 : pos);
                    listToggleListener.OnListExpanded(category.isSelected());
                    notifyItemChanged(0);
                }
            });
        }

        public void setData(CuisineCategory category) {
            cuisineCategory.setText(category.getTitle());
            cuisineItemToggle.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, category.isSelected() ? R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_accent_24dp : R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_accent_24dp));

            cuisineItemList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            cuisineItemList.setAdapter(new RestaurantMenuAdapter(context));
            cuisineItemList.setVisibility(category.isSelected() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = rootLayout.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = category.isSelected() ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT : ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            rootLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }

    public interface CuisineListToggleListener {
        void OnListExpanded(boolean selected);
    }
}
```

in my second adapter dataList array is that I want to load it dynamically so using retrofit I fetch some data to ArrayList using below code

```
cuisineAdapter = new CuisineAdapter(RestaurantDetailActivity.this,dataList);
```

and setting up the adapter like this

```
private void setupCuisineRecycler() {
        linearLayoutManager = new MyLinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        cuisineRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        cuisineRecycler.setAdapter(new CuisineAdapter(getContext(), new CuisineAdapter.CuisineListToggleListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnListExpanded(final boolean selected) {
                if (selected) {
                    cuisineRecycler.scrollToPosition(0);
                }
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        linearLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(!selected);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        }));
    }
```

now I want to bind data to datalist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** do it.

```
this.dataList = mydataList;<- this is not working
```

In your second constructor `mydataList` **doesn't exist**.

You can do something like:

```
  public class CuisineAdapter{

    private ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList;

    public CuisineAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.mydataList = mydataList;
    }

    public CuisineAdapter(Context context, 
                          ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList, 
                          CuisineListToggleListener listToggleListener) {
            this(context, mydataList);
            this.listToggleListener = listToggleListener;
    }

    public CuisineAdapter(Context context, 
                          CuisineListToggleListener listToggleListener) {
            this.context = context;
            this.listToggleListener = listToggleListener;
    }

    public ArrayList<CuisineCategory> getMydataList(){
       return mydataList;
    }

    public void setMydataList(ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList){
       this.mydataList= mydataList;
    }

  }
```

Then you use it with:

```
CuisineAdapter adapter = new CuisineAdapter(context, mydataList);
```

or:

```
CuisineAdapter adapter = new CuisineAdapter(context, listToggleListener);
adapter.setMydataList(mydataList);
```

Comment: can I do this without changing the second constructor parameters?

Comment: @AseshaGeorge You can create an empty arrayList with `this.dataList = new ArrayList<>();`, but you can't set the arrayList to `mydataList` because it doesn't exist when you are creating the object.

Comment: if you don't want to change your constructor and still need "mydataList" ,you would require to initialize this variable using a setter and call it or create a third constructor as suggested below by @Martin .

Comment: can you give me an example for setter and call for mydataList?

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Added an example.

Comment: thank you for the example but how to use it in the second constructor. please see my question. exactly same places I want to access the array.

Comment: @AseshaGeorge I read your question. You should read the comments above and the answer. In the same place, without passing it as variable in the constructor you **can't use it** because you can't access the variable used in another constructor, you can only call another constructor passing the required input parameters.

Comment: The above answer suits your question. I think your problem statement is different and the question you have posted seems like a solution thought by you in first place . It would be more helpful for you if you give your problem statement .

As much as i have understood you already have a constructor in place which you can't change or have no control over the code,now you want to inject one more variable value into it, this could only be done using a setter or you would need to change the code as suggested above

Comment: thank you very much for your response I tried the example I am getting data when I check in log it's showing only one value not full array please see my edit code in my question

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Something is wrong here.
CuisineAdapter adapter = new CuisineAdapter(context, mydataList);  You are creating another object in the constructor, you are not initializing the same object. Also in this way mydataList is not passed.

Comment: so it's not possible to get mydatalist into constructer? coz I need to use it hear only, I can't change this constructer all the places. can you help me to get mydatalist into this constructer

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Sorry. Check also the nsharma's comment but for me it is not clear what is your final goal. **When the constructor code is running and mydatalist is not passed as parameter, mydatalist simply doesn't exist in that object**.

Comment: thank you for helping me I just added full code. I thought its an easy process its become more complicated. please see my edited question

Comment: as you said I modified the constructor I am getting values as I required but in the set adapter what should I put in the 2 nd argument after getcontext().

Comment: The parameter is CuisineListToggleListener. It should work as you reported in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to change the existing constructors - just add a third one constructor:

```
public CuisineAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CuisineCategory> mydataList), CuisineListToggleListener) 
    ...
}
```

So that `Context`, `ArrayList<>` and `ToggleListener` will be available at the same time.